# Using results of executeQueryAsync with JSGRID

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I understand I can retrieve the list data using `context.load(data)` and later firing

```
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

But I still dont understand how to use the data retrieved to update the SharePoint list. I don't want to create a new list in `function onQuerySucceeded()`. Rather I want to update the existing list.

```
function onQuerySucceeded(){
  var fetchedData = data.getEnumerator();
 //.... How can I populate this fetchedData to existing list. I believe it should be feasible using jsgrid, but I have no idea how to do that.

}
```

I can only write javascript but not c# for this project.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of JSGrid is that you have to use both server-side code (C#) and client-side code (JavaScript). So if you cannot use C#, then I don't think you can use JSGrid (and if you can, please let me know !!).

So you'll have to use the JavaScript Microsoft API to get the data from a list, update them and so on. This API is not clear or easy to use. Also you don't provide enought context code to be able to help you more than that...

At the end, I'd recommend you to look at my JavaScript Library called [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/). It should be simpler to use. For example to update a list with a WHERE Clause you can do :

```
$SP().list("List Name").update({Title:"Ok"},{where:"Status = 'Complete'"});
```

Comment: JsGrid can be used purely client-side, I did it. It has extensive (and undocumented, unfortunately) javascript API. But the thing is, it seems the question does not really relate to JsGrid...

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev I'd be glad if you can share some code, somewhere :-)